# Remove duplicates from a list and remove respective elements from second list in python

Tags: python, list, duplicates

I have two lists. One contains strings, that represent names and one contains integers that represent the persons. For every name there is a respective number and I can access each name because they are on the same index. However, there are many duplicate names and I want to delete all duplicate names. I thought of using a set to delete the duplicates and then convert it back to a list like this :

```
names = (list(set(names)))
```

However now, how can I keep the same phone numbers that are the respective for the elements kept in the set.

An Example.

Before:

```
Index    Name        Number
0        Alexander   12345
1        Elena       45678
2        John        76542
3        Alexander   43256
4        John        45024
5        David       69438
```

After:

```
NewIndex Name        Number
0        Alexander   12345
1        Elena       45678
2        John        76542
3        David       69438
```

Comment: So you want to keep the first encountered number for a duplicate name?

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh It doesn't really matter, I just want it to be the respective number every time. For example if it chose the second Alexander to keep the number 43256.

Comment: how do you `choose` which alexander, do you instead want to keep all numbers in a list

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh No I only want one number, which is the respective number, I don't care for all the numbers. We can choose always to keep the first one.

Comment: So choosing the first number is fine then? Also is `Index` something auto generated? Are the two lists in question only `Name` and `Number`, can you also add how `names` list looks like

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing you can do is zip `Name` and `Number` together and then make a dict. Since a dict hashes *only* based on the value of the key, then the value remains still associated with the name, but is otherwise left untouched:

```
name_dict = dict(zip(names, numbers))
new_names, new_numbers = zip(*list(name_dict.items()))
```

Now, `new_names` still corresponds to `new_numbers` by index, but there should be no duplicate elements remaining.

---

One caveat with this approach is that the *last* occurrence of a given name is the one whose number takes precedence (e.g. `"Alexander"` would correspond to `43256`, not to `12345`). You should be able to fix this by doing `dict(reversed(zip(names, numbers)))` to switch the order in which the `dict` reads and assigns keys.

Comment: Or just use a traditional for loop, and add a key-value pair only if it is not already  added, instead of reversing a zip, which is unncessary extra computation

Comment: That's fair, but the other answers cover that already. As I understand it, idiomatic python code values elegance and brevity over speed/efficiency, which is what I've presented here

Comment: I was talking about `dict(reversed(zip(names, numbers)))`, idiomatic code is not the same as having a bigger time complexity than what is needed. You end up taking doing double the computational time that is needed

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`dict.setdefault()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault) to just store the default first name found inside a dictionary:

```
data = [
    ('Alexander', 12345),
    ('Elena', 45678),
    ('John', 45678),
    ('Alexander', 43256),
    ('John', 45024),
    ('David', 69438)
]

result = {}
for name, number in data:
    result.setdefault(name, number)

print(list(result.items()))
# [('Alexander', 12345), ('Elena', 45678), ('John', 45678), ('David', 69438)]
```

Answer (score 0):

For this array

```
arr = [ ['Alexander',   12345],
        ['Elena',       45678],
        ['John',        76542],
        ['Alexander',   43256],
        ['John',        45024],
        ['David',       69438] ]
```

Assuming you want to keep the first encountered number,

```
names = [a[0] for a in arr]
names_unique = list(set(names))

newarr = [ [name, arr[names.index(name)][1] ] for name in names_unique ]
```

This will yield:

```
[['Elena',      45678],
 ['David',      69438],
 ['Alexander',  12345],
 ['John',       76542]]
```

This is not the faster solution but for arrays with a length smaller than a million, it will be done under a second. The `.index` can be pretty expensive for huge arrays so in this case you can use a classic single for loop or try to get a pre-sorted array.